# djangoアプリのエラーについて

Tags: python, git, django, heroku

お教えください。
djangoアプリをherokuでデプロイはできたのですが、
`$heroku open`でアプリを開こうとするとアプリケーション
エラーとなってしまいます。

下記は実行後のログです。

ディレクトリ構成は下記githubのURLをご参照ください。
https://github.com/yamady0704/blog1/tree/master

アプリケーションエラーの解消方法をお教え頂けませんでしょうか。

```
2018-10-24T13:21:13.550840+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 345, in halt
2018-10-24T13:21:13.551268+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2018-10-24T13:21:13.551306+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
2018-10-24T13:21:13.551915+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
2018-10-24T13:21:13.551952+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_chld
2018-10-24T13:21:13.552291+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2018-10-24T13:21:13.552329+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2018-10-24T13:21:13.552838+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2018-10-24T13:21:13.552918+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2018-10-24T13:21:13.673819+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-10-24T13:21:13.690224+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2018-10-24T13:21:13.692127+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-10-24T13:21:25.798904+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn mysite.wsgi --log-file -`
2018-10-24T13:21:29.745356+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-10-24T13:21:29.623878+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-24 13:21:29 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2018-10-24T13:21:29.629375+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-24 13:21:29 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:37250 (4)
2018-10-24T13:21:29.632634+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-24 13:21:29 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2018-10-24T13:21:29.646347+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-24 13:21:29 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2018-10-24T13:21:29.701398+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-24 13:21:29 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2018-10-24T13:21:31.055948+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-24 22:21:31 +0900] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-10-24T13:21:31.055972+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-10-24T13:21:31.055975+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2018-10-24T13:21:31.055977+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2018-10-24T13:21:31.055979+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2018-10-24T13:21:31.055980+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2018-10-24T13:21:31.055982+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2018-10-24T13:21:31.055984+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-10-24T13:21:31.055986+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-10-24T13:21:31.055987+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2018-10-24T13:21:31.055989+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2018-10-24T13:21:31.055991+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-10-24T13:21:31.055992+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2018-10-24T13:21:31.055994+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-10-24T13:21:31.055996+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2018-10-24T13:21:31.055997+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2018-10-24T13:21:31.055999+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/mysite/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
2018-10-24T13:21:31.056001+00:00 app[web.1]: from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
2018-10-24T13:21:31.056218+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whitenoise'
2018-10-24T13:21:31.056869+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-24 22:21:31 +0900] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2018-10-24T13:21:31.209837+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-24 22:21:31 +0900] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-10-24T13:21:31.209841+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-10-24T13:21:31.209846+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2018-10-24T13:21:31.209848+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2018-10-24T13:21:31.209850+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2018-10-24T13:21:31.209852+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2018-10-24T13:21:31.209853+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2018-10-24T13:21:31.209855+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-10-24T13:21:31.209857+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-10-24T13:21:31.209859+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2018-10-24T13:21:31.209860+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2018-10-24T13:21:31.209862+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-10-24T13:21:31.209864+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2018-10-24T13:21:31.209865+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-10-24T13:21:31.209867+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2018-10-24T13:21:31.209869+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2018-10-24T13:21:31.209871+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/mysite/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
2018-10-24T13:21:31.209873+00:00 app[web.1]: from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
2018-10-24T13:21:31.209882+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whitenoise'
2018-10-24T13:21:31.210289+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-24 22:21:31 +0900] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2018-10-24T13:21:31.217392+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=yamadyblog.herokuapp.com request_id=e679bfd9-165b-4525-9722-7108662edda3 fwd="180.4.120.65" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=199ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2018-10-24T13:21:31.214678+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=yamadyblog.herokuapp.com request_id=fc2b4673-38fb-465e-8410-7fedf7970e12 fwd="180.4.120.65" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=812ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2018-10-24T13:21:31.315067+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-10-24T13:21:31.315137+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 210, in run
2018-10-24T13:21:31.315690+00:00 app[web.1]: self.sleep()
2018-10-24T13:21:31.315729+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 360, in sleep
2018-10-24T13:21:31.316210+00:00 app[web.1]: ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
2018-10-24T13:21:31.316246+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_chld
2018-10-24T13:21:31.316612+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2018-10-24T13:21:31.316687+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2018-10-24T13:21:31.317157+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2018-10-24T13:21:31.317261+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2018-10-24T13:21:31.317295+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-24T13:21:31.317298+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2018-10-24T13:21:31.317299+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-24T13:21:31.317330+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-10-24T13:21:31.317390+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
2018-10-24T13:21:31.317585+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
2018-10-24T13:21:31.317615+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 61, in run
2018-10-24T13:21:31.317836+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2018-10-24T13:21:31.317899+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 223, in run
2018-10-24T13:21:31.318189+00:00 app[web.1]: super(Application, self).run()
2018-10-24T13:21:31.318261+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2018-10-24T13:21:31.318506+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2018-10-24T13:21:31.318541+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 232, in run
2018-10-24T13:21:31.318906+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2018-10-24T13:21:31.319343+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 345, in halt
2018-10-24T13:21:31.320161+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2018-10-24T13:21:31.320435+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
2018-10-24T13:21:31.321193+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
2018-10-24T13:21:31.321226+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_chld
2018-10-24T13:21:31.321534+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2018-10-24T13:21:31.321565+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2018-10-24T13:21:31.322336+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2018-10-24T13:21:31.322378+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2018-10-24T13:21:31.442772+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2018-10-24T13:21:31.424299+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-10-24T13:21:36.535063+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=yamadyblog.herokuapp.com request_id=f615fd99-24fe-4828-aa5b-25ec4c15c3c2 fwd="180.4.120.65" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-24T13:21:36.812790+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/admin" host=yamadyblog.herokuapp.com request_id=31772c16-43db-48f7-be1f-e84c88dc1bce fwd="180.4.120.65" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-24T13:21:37.860462+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=yamadyblog.herokuapp.com request_id=07b312b9-dea8-4cc6-937a-b0536af5fcb3 fwd="180.4.120.65" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-24T13:21:36.575388+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=yamadyblog.herokuapp.com request_id=8283bee3-5884-409f-80b4-6ebe1bad3028 fwd="180.4.120.65" dyno=web.1 connect=5020ms service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ログに以下のエラーが出ています。

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whitenoise'
```

[requirements.txt](https://github.com/yamady0704/blog1/blob/master/requirements.txt) にwhitenosiseが指定されていないのが原因でしょう。

Answer (score -1):

requirements.txtに`whitenoise==3.3.1`を追加後、再デプロイを行ったところアプリケーションエラーが解消されました。

Comment: requirement.textではなくrequirements.txt ですよね。あと、Takayuki さんの回答の承認で済む内容と思いますが。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: ご指摘の通り、requirements.txtでした。回答承認についても理解しておらず、申し訳ございませんでした。Takayukiさんの回答を承認いたしました。

Comment: とんでもないです。ありがとうございます。